# Different events for different breakpoint sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Trying to make an element clickable on a small breakpoint (mobile devices or skinny browser window), but hoverable on a large breakpoint

I'm creating a different event depending on screen size, but when resizing from Large to Small size, the Large size event still triggers.

I think I need to remove the event listener when the screen size changes, but have gotten stuck doing this.

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/777333/pen/wvoZYga

```
let hello = document.querySelector('.hello')
let width = $(window).width()
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
  let width = $(window).width()
  if ( width < 600 ) {
    hello.onclick = () => {
      alert('mobile')
    }
  } else {
    hello.onmouseover = () => {
      alert('desktop')
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, check for the screen width *inside*  your event handlers.

Comment: Isn't he already doing that?

Comment: @weltschmerz No. He's deciding *which* handlers to bind when the page loads or whenever it is resized, which would possibly - in case of the resize handler - require unbinding previously bound handlers.

Comment: @connexo Thanks, you have totally just pointed me in the right direction here, seems to be working well